# How to get current latitude and longitude values in codename one

Tags: codenameone

Im trying to get my current latitude and longitude values using LocationManager in Codename One but the values i'm getting is for a different location.
Here is my code:

```
LocationManager locationManager = LocationManager.getLocationManager();
Location location = locationManager.getCurrentLocation();
Double loc1= location.getLatitude();
Double loc2= location.getLongitude();
System.out.println("Latitude: "+loc1);
System.out.println("Longitude: "+loc2);
```

Output:

Latitude: 40.715353
Longitude: -74.00497299999999

My correct current Latitude and Longitude values are 3.xxxx and 101.xxxx respectively.

Please how can I get these correct values from LocationManager?

Comment: Thank you very much Diamond. I'm very greatful

Answer (score 3):

That is default location on Simulator.

Note that you can't get your actual location on Simulator without entering it yourself.

To set your simulator to use your current location, Click **Simulate** on your simulator and select **Location Simulation**. Enter your LatLong values for **Available** and Click Update. The Google map will shift view to your location, So would your app.

You can keep Location Simulator open while you test your app.

On a side note, if your app needs a real time location I would suggest you use getCurrentLocationAsync(). Below is an example:

```
InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
Dialog ipDlg = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
Location location = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocationSync(30000);
ipDlg.dispose();
if (location == null) {
    try {
        location = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocation();
    } catch (IOException err) {
        Dialog.show("Location Error", "Unable to find your current location, please be sure that your GPS is turned on", "OK", null);
        return;
    }
}
Double loc1 = location.getLatitude();
Double loc2 = location.getLongitude();
Log.p("Latitude: " + loc1);
Log.p("Longitude: " + loc2);
```